# How to type an object that can have any keys and avoid the Property 'xxx' does not exist on type '{}' warning?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that can receive an object whose entries can be anything. The object is typed as such: `myObj: {}`.

I perform a conditional check on `myObj.count`. Typescript displays the following error:

> Property 'count' does not exist on type '{}'

How to avoid this (I don't want to write @ts-ignore), I need a clean typing.

Is `myObj?:{count?: number, [key:string]: any}` acceptable, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `myObj` to **always** have the count property then don't use the `?`:

```js
myObj?:{count: number, [key:string]: any}
```

If you want `myObj` to sometimes have `count` then do it like you said:

```js
myObj?:{count?: number, [key:string]: any}
```

However, the second one won't help you avoid a check to see if the property exists.

Note though, that this will only help check the property exists statically and if you're casting to this type, the property may still be null (even in the first example)

Comment: Yes, the count property may appear sometimes. So option 2 is correct.